# How can I use pytest options as fixture and not repeat myself?

Tags: python, pytest, dry, fixtures

I have a test suite with a `conftest.py` defining some options and some fixtures to retrieve them:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption("--ip", action="store")
  parser.addoption("--port", action="store")

@pytest.fixture
def ip(request):
  return request.config.getoption("ip")

@pytest.fixture
def port(request):
  return request.config.getoption("ip")
```

(I slipped in a copy-paste error to make a point)

My tests can very eloquently express the options they need:

```
def test_can_ping(ip):
  ...

def test_can_net_cat(ip, port):
  ...
```

But ...

I'm trying to avoid duplicating myself here: I have to specify the name of the config parameter in three places to make it work.

I could have avoided the copy-paste error if I had something that looked like this:

```
# does not exist:
@pytest.option_fixture
def ip(request, parser):
  return request.config.getoption(this_function_name)
```

or this

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
  # does not exist: an as_fixture parameter
  parser.addoption("--ip", action="store", as_fixture=True)
  parser.addoption("--port", action="store", as_fixture=True)
```

Is there a way to tell pytest to add an option *and* a corresponding
fixture to achieve DRY/SPOT code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I came to something working. It is probably not the best way to do it but it is quite satisfying I think.
*All code below have been added to the `conftest.py` module, except the two tests.*

First define a dictionary containing the options data:

```
options = {
    'port': {'action': 'store', 'help': 'TCP port', 'type': int},
    'ip': {'action': 'store', 'help': 'IP address', 'type': str},
}
```

We could do without `help` and `type`, but it will have a certain utility later.

Then you can use this `options` to create the pytest options:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    for option, config in options.items():
        parser.addoption(f'--{option}', **config)
```

At this point, `pytest --help` gives this (note the `help` data usage which provides convenient doc):

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
...
custom options:
  --port=PORT           TCP port
  --ip=IP               IP address
```

Finally we have to define the fixtures. I did this by providing a `make_fixture` function which is used in a loop at `conftest.py` reading to dynamically create fixtures and add them to the global scope of the module:

```
def make_fixture(option, config):
    func = lambda request: request.config.getoption(option)
    func.__doc__ = config['help']
    globals()[option] = pytest.fixture()(func)


for option, config in options.items():
    make_fixture(option, config)
```

Again, the 'help' data is used to build a docstring to the created fixtures and document them. Thus, invoking `pytest --fixtures` prints this:

```
...
---- fixtures defined from conftest ----
ip
    IP address
port
    TCP port
```

Invoking `pytest --port 80 --ip 127.0.0.1`, with the two following very simple tests, seems to validate the trick (Here the `type` data shows its utility, it has made pytest convert the port to an `int`, instead of a string):

```
def test_ip(ip):
    assert ip == '127.0.0.1'


def test_ip_port(ip, port):
    assert ip == '127.0.0.1'
    assert port == 80
```

(Very interesting question, I would like to see more like this one)

Comment: I'm wondering about the recursion in `make_fixture`: Why doesn't that create an infinite loop?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: oops, it is an edit mistake, it is fixed

Comment: Now there's a DRY solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the `pytest` decorators, create one of your own:

```
parse_options = []

@addOption(parse_options)
@pytest
def ip(...): ...
```

A decorator doesn't *have* to modify the function which is passed in. So in this case, look at the method object, use the `f.__name__` to get the name and add an entry in the list `parse_options` for it.

The next step is to modify `pytest_addoption` to iterate over the list and create the options. At the time when the function is being executed, the decorators should have done their work.

Comment: Quite a nice hint!   I could even leave the `ip` function empty, and decorate a fully new function that retreives the parameter based on the function name.